# How to get the params in a Express route when I am using app.use() for the home page in my server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So, basically I have this middleware on my `server.js` file: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))` for the home page.

It's possible to show the same home page when a user hit this route: `app.get('/ref=:refId')` and still show `localhost:3000/ref=Asldoe2231sSLexe2` in the address bar?

Now I know that I can achieve this behavior using query string like so: `localhost:3000/?ref=Asldoe2231sSLexe2` and then get the query string using `req.query.ref` on the server, the problem is I cannot use `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))` directly if I have this route `app.get('/', (req, res) => {...`. How can I solve this?

My goal is either grab the `refId` value on the client, send it to the server and check if exists in the database or check it directly as soon as the client hit the route, I rather prefer the second option which is a cleaner way of doing it.

Comment: which page you render has nothing to do with what you do in the route definition. You can render which ever HTML page you would like when you define `res.render('your page')`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do don't have a relationship with 
`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))`. It is used for giving the path to static files such as CSS, images in your application.

You can get `refId` by `req.query.ref` and pass it to the page you are rendering.
One way is :
`res.locals.refId = req.query.ref` and in your view use `refid`
Second way is :
`res.render('<file_you_are_rendering>',{refId:req.query.ref})`

Comment: Where do the `<file_you_are_rendering>` came from?